# vue and vuex: Evrything works, just want to see how shorten a code. Is there sort of watcher or what's the best way to shorten a code?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, watch

Here are actions on how I implemented a cart. Don't really try to get what's going on the main point is a last line of code in each of a functions. Which is

`localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart));`

those actions call mutations which in there turn changing variable `cart`, therefore after every change I save new cart in localStorage. Code works, but I don't like duplication. Is there better way doing ? I thought probably watcher on changing a state variable ?  But does anybody know if it exists ? And how to use it?

```
export async function removeItemFromCart({state, getters, commit}, id){
  let ind  = getters.index(id);

  commit('removeFromCart', ind);
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart)); //here
}

export async function setCnt({state, getters, commit, rootGetters}, { id, cnt }){
  let ind  = getters.index(id);

  if(state.cart[ind].cnt + cnt >= 1 && state.cart[ind].cnt + cnt <= rootGetters['watches/item'](id).cnt)
    commit('addCnt', { ind, cnt})
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart)); //here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way could be creating another action for setting cart in local storage.

```
export async function removeItemFromCart({state, getters, commit}, id){
  let ind  = getters.index(id);

  commit('removeFromCart', ind);
  commit('setCart', state.cart);
}

export async function setCnt({state, getters, commit, rootGetters}, { id, cnt }){
  let ind  = getters.index(id);

  if(state.cart[ind].cnt + cnt >= 1 && state.cart[ind].cnt + cnt <= rootGetters['watches/item'](id).cnt)
    commit('addCnt', { ind, cnt})
  commit('setCart', state.cart);
}

export function setCart({commit}, cart) {
  localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}
```